# Haskell: type classes: multiple inheritance example

Tags: haskell, inheritance

I came to know that we can achieve multiple inheritance using type classes. I had written small haskell code, but unable to figure out the problem.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

class (Eq a, Show a) => C a where
    getHashCode :: a -> Integer
    getHashCode obj = 123


type Id = Int
type Name = String

data Employee = Employee Id Name deriving C
```

When i tried to load above code, I am getting following error. Any help on this.

```
 No instance for (Eq Employee)
      arising from the 'deriving' clause of a data type declaration
   Possible fix:
      use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
        so you can specify the instance context yourself
    When deriving the instance for (C Employee)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I searched google some time, but unable to found good example for multiple inheritance. it will be helpful if you provide some info, example on multiple inheritance in Haskell.

Reference: https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 10):

Saying

```
class (Eq a, Show a) => C a where
```

does not mean that types that implement `C` automatically implement `Eq` and `Show`, it means that they must first implement `Eq` and `Show` before they can implement `C`.

A `class` in Haskell is not the same as a `class` in Java, either, it's closer to an interface, but it can't be used in the same ways (and shouldn't).  Haskell doesn't actually have a concept of inheritance or classes in the OOP sense, as it's not an OOP language.

However, if you want to have `Eq` and `Show` instances automatically for a type, just add them to the `deriving` clause of the data type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We can derive more than one type class, but my question was I want to use the statement 'class (Eq a, Show a) => C a where', with this how can i resolve the error.